# Mercurial batch pull operation

Tags: mercurial, batch-file, pull

I have several repositories for personal use and I back them up on my main server. There are quite a few and it takes quite a bit of time to perform a pull operation on every single repository.

Does mercurial support batch pull of several repositories? If so, how do I go about it? If not, is there a relatively simple solution?

I am using Windows and use TortoiseHg (but I have no problem with using the command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the repositories are static, a simple solution would be to write a batch file to pull from all those repositories. But no, mercurial does not support this directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `hook` on the Master server to push to a slave server? Add this to the project's `hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg push -f https://hg.server2.com/TheRepo
```

FYI about `changegroup` from the `hgrc` help file:

> changegroup:
>   Run after a changegroup has been added
>   via push, pull or unbundle. ID of the
>   first new changeset is in $HG_NODE.
>   URL from which changes came is in
>   $HG_URL.

So when a change group comes in on the server, it will `hg push` the changes to yet another server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a top level repository where I have a few batch files and a textfile containing all repositories.

i.e. repolist.txt

```
Repo1
# Comment
Folder\Repo2
Repo3
```

and the batch file hgrpull.bat looks like:

```
REM First pull top level repository to get updated repolist etc
hg pull --update --quiet

REM Find path to server repository
FOR /F %%x IN ('hg showconfig paths.default') DO SET HGSERVER=%%x

REM Now pull or clone each repository
FOR /F "delims=; eol=#" %%x IN (repolist.txt) DO (
    If EXIST "%%x\.hg" (
        ECHO Pull %%x
        hg pull --update --quiet --repository "%%x"
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Clone %%x
        IF NOT EXIST "%%x" MKDIR "%%x"
        hg clone --pull "%HGSERVER%\%%x" "%%x"
    )
)
```

I also got some batch files to perform actions on all repositories. (status/incoming/outgoing etc). They are all based on the following hgr.bat:

```
FOR /F "delims=; eol=#" %%x IN (repolist.txt) DO (
    ECHO ** %%x
    hg %1 --repository "%%x" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6
)
```

Pull/clone all repositories: `hgrpull`

Check status on all repositories: `hgr st -mard`